# Kotlin: Convert map to Any Object

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to convert a mutable map to Any object. For example:

```
    Val map = mutableMapOf("name" to "michael", "age" to "12")

Var user = map.toObject //Any Object i want

And :

Print((user as User).name)
//output michael
Print((user as User).age)
//output 12


Class User(val name, val age){

}
```

because I am creating a generic function. by what way do this?

Comment: Have you tried  **var user = map as Any** ?

Comment: You are probably looking for Dynamic type, please check this link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49861013/1843331

Comment: You can't, and that's a good thing.  Lots of types don't want to let you arbitrarily create an instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Gson, by serializing the map to json, and then deserializing the json to any object. Conversion in both directions shown here:

```
val gson = Gson()

//convert a map to a data class
inline fun <reified T> Map<String, Any>.toDataClass(): T {
    return convert()
}

//convert a data class to a map
fun <T> T.serializeToMap(): Map<String, Any> {
    return convert()
}

//convert an object of type I to type O
inline fun <I, reified O> I.convert(): O {
    val json = gson.toJson(this)
    return gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<O>() {}.type)
}
```

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860916/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-data-class-object-to-map/56347214#56347214)