# Transform data class to map kotlin

Tags: kotlin, casting, maps, data-class

My problem is that I need to transform a data class in kotlin to a map, because I need to work with this structure as a requirement, because this response will be used for a groovy classes and there is a post-process where there are validations iterations etc, with this map. My data class is the next (Podcast):

```
data class PodCast(val id: String, val type: String, val items: List<Item>, val header: Header, val cellType:String? = "")

data class Item(val type: String, val parentId: String, val parentType: String, val id: String, val action: Action, val isNew: Boolean)

data class Header(val color: String, val label: String)

data class Action(val type: String, val url: String)
```

I made the transformation manually, but I need a more sophisticated way to achieve this task.

Thanks.

Comment: What should the `Map` look like? You made the transformation manually...where? What sort of approach qualifies as "more sophisticated"?

Comment: Which class do you need to transform into a `Map`?

Comment: The map should be a key value map, more sophisticated I mean a generic way to achieve this.

Comment: "_a key value map_". That's what a map _is_. What should be the keys and what should be the values? What have you already tried and why isn't it generic enough?

Comment: I need to transform this in a map because I have to work with this map since groovy and there is a post-process with this map, itereations, ask for files etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java introspection: object to map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796187/java-introspection-object-to-map)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Kotlin data class object to map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860916/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-data-class-object-to-map)

Comment: The final one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860916/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-data-class-object-to-map) is the opposite way. I need to transforma an object to a map. And the other one is the java way (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796187/java-introspection-object-to-map), I am looking for a more kolin way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this very simple. I got the properties of the object, just using the .properties groovy method, which gave me the object as a map.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with Gson, by serializing the data class to json, and then deserializing the json to a map. Conversion in both directions shown here:

```
val gson = Gson()

//convert a data class to a map
fun <T> T.serializeToMap(): Map<String, Any> {
    return convert()
}

//convert a map to a data class
inline fun <reified T> Map<String, Any>.toDataClass(): T {
    return convert()
}

//convert an object of type I to type O
inline fun <I, reified O> I.convert(): O {
    val json = gson.toJson(this)
    return gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<O>() {}.type)
}
```

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860916/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-data-class-object-to-map/56347214#56347214)