# Convert ArrayList<SomeClass> to Map in kotlin

Tags: android, dictionary, arraylist, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to convert ArrayList of some class to a map by it's fields , if the filed name is "firstName"
and it's value in the object that I am trying to convert is Sam than the key would be <"firstName", "Sam"> 
but the value is not always String, and the name of the key is the same name as the filed.

Comment: can you show us an example, how the JSON representation of your model class looks like? also how your map will look when you convert the specific model class?

Comment: This may help- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354581/97714

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use `associateByTo` to pull it off.

```
Given your list:

val fieldMap = mutableMapOf<Any, Any>()

list.asscoiateByTo(fieldMap, { SomeClass::someField.returnType.javaType }, { it.someField })
```

You will need the kotlin.reflect.jvm package as well

Comment: Thanks it seems like what i was looking for. I have never used reflection before, is it adviced to use it preformance wise?

Comment: Depending on the scope of what you need it for depends on it's impact. You shouldn't notice it for this.