# How to convert Data Class to HashMap for Firestore in Kotlin View Model, kotlinx.serialization not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a firestore document in Kotlin, and I have this data class:

```
    val profileDoc = Profile(
        username = queriedUsername,
        device_id = listOf<String>(),
        img = profile_img,
        isDeleted = false,
        hasInitialisedTags = false,
        isGridViewSelected = false,
        isAddButtonHintHidden = false,
        isTaskTypeHintHidden = false,
        newSpacesBadgeNumber = 0,
        savedSpacesBadgeNumber = 0
    )
```

And then I'm converting it to a `hashMapOf`:

```
    val ProfileData = hashMapOf(
        "device_id" to profileDoc.device_id,
        "email" to email,
        "username" to queriedUsername,
        "img" to profile_img,
        "isDeleted" to profileDoc.isDeleted,
        "hasInitialisedTags" to profileDoc.hasInitialisedTags,
        "isGridViewSelected" to profileDoc.isGridViewSelected,
        "isAddButtonHintHidden" to profileDoc.isAddButtonHintHidden,
        "isTaskTypeHintHidden" to profileDoc.isTaskTypeHintHidden,
        "newSpacesBadgeNumber" to profileDoc.newSpacesBadgeNumber,
        "savedSpacesBadgeNumber" to profileDoc.savedSpacesBadgeNumber
    )
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to convert it without having to repeat the same code?

I've tried using [kotlin.serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638249/19020089), but it doesn't seem to work. Android Studio doesn't know where to import `ExperimentalSerializationApi` or anything else. I've added the implementation and it built properly, but it still says:

```
Unresolved reference: ExperimentalSerializationApi
```

So is there another way?

Comment: So you basically need to map the properties of an object of type `Profile` to HashMap, right?

Comment: Why don't you use `toObject()` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try the Kotlin Reflection library.

First, you must add kotlin-reflect in your depedencies

```
  depedencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
}
```

This could help you to learn how to use kotlin-reflect to convert Data class to HashMap
https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/data-class-to-map

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/kotlin/kotlin-convert-data-class-to-map/

I hope these resources help you to solve your problem